# Why is a div's padding 100% even when it is set to 0

Tags: html, css

I have some centered content on a web page for a small project that I am working on. The username and password text should be next to their corresponding input boxes, and only drop down into the position they are in right now if the screen is too slim. When I inspect the problematic text in chrome, it says that the padding is `100%`, even though it is set to 0 in the css.

Here is the problem area:

```
<div id = 'log in stuff' class = 'logInContainer' hidden>
            <h1>Log In:</h1>
            
            <div class = 'small'>Username: </div> <input id = 'username'>
            <br>
            <div class = 'small'>Password: </div> <input id = 'password'>
            <br>
            <button id = 'create account'>create account</button>
            <button id = 'log in'>log in</button>
            <br>
            <div id = 'log in problem'></div>
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
                .small{
                    color:#0071a5;
                    font-size: 3em;
                    width:50%;
                    margin:0;
                    height: 12%;
                    padding:0;
                    border:0px;
                }
                input{
                    width:40%;
                    margin: 0;
                    height: 7%;
                    border:0.5em solid blue;
                    border-radius: 0.5em;
                    background-color: #5d6f72;
                }

                .logInContainer{
                    margin: auto;
                    width: 100%;
                    position: absolute;
                    top:1%;
                    text-align: center;
                    left:0%;
                    height: 100%;
                }
```

Currently It looks like this:
[image]

I would like the input boxes to be next to the text, not below it, and have the text and the input centered horizontally. This is my first real HTML project, so i'm relatively new to css. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the label tag to make sure that your text falls next to your input tag. This code below worked perfectly fine for me try it yourself :-). And i even added the form tag so you know why the input field is smaller.

```
 <div id = 'log in stuff' class = 'logInContainer' hidden>
    <h1>Log In:</h1>
    <form>
        <label class="small" for='username'>Username: </label>
        <input name="username" id = 'username'>
        <br>
        <label for="password" class="small">Password: </label>
        <input name="password" id = 'password'>
    </form>
    <br>
    <button id = 'create account'>create account</button>
    <button id = 'log in'>log in</button>
    <br>
    <div id = 'log in problem'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because "div" is a block element so add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to "small" class in your code to be as follow:

```
.small{
    color:#0071a5;
    font-size: 3em;
    width:50%;
    margin:0;
    height: 12%;
    padding:0;
    border:0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```